# When WPF Window Starts and Finishes reDrawing?

Tags: wpf, window, redraw

I have a Main View with a frame. In this frame I show all other Views.
I do it by

```
mainView.frMain.Navigate(aPage);
```

In a aPage I have mainRoot - this is the main Grid in Xaml.
But after call

```
mainView.frMain.Navigate(aPage);
```

before call

```
private void mainRoot_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
```

I wait some seconds.
And after finish method

```
private void mainRoot_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
```

before finally Window is showed I wait some seconds again.

So, I want in this time Show "Please wait..." window.
My question is - when I should Show() and when I should Hide() "Please wait..." window?
When does Window start reDrawing and when does it finish?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this example:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFsplashscreen.aspx (Just to reuse Splasher helper and maybe SplashScreen window)

If I understand well what you want to achieve:

- place ShowSplash() in Application.Navigating event
- place CloseSplash() in Application.LoadCompleted event

Comment: I show my Views not only onStartApplication.
I have many Views. And I need "Please wait..." every time when new View is Showed.